# Set the globaloptions in the HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm running a local Highcharts Export Server based on Java and PhantomJS and 
I am trying to disable the UTC time zone global in the charts. Therefor I am using the globaloptions to reach it but I do not know what is the right way to set it in the highCharts.

This way does not work for my case but it works in HighChart jsfiddle.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
    useUTC: false
  }
});
```

since I am rendering the HighCharts in the PDF report and I have to set it as global.

**The Whole HighCharts:**

https://jsfiddle.net/0zw7gq82/

```
Highcharts.chart('container',
 {
     chart: {
         type: 'columnrange',
         inverted: true,
         height: 200,
         spacingLeft: 30
     },
     credits: {
         enabled: false
     },
     title: {
         text: null,
         style: {
             "fontSize": "10px"
         }
     },
     subTitle: {
         text: null
     },
     legend: {
         enabled: false,
     },
     plotOptions: {
         series: {
             pointWidth: 30
         }
     },
     xAxis: {
         min: 1,
         max: 1,
         categories: ['', ''],
         title: {
             text: null
         },
         labels: {
             rotation: 90
         },
         gridLineWidth: 0
     },
     yAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         title: {
             text: null
         },
         labels: {
             rotation: -45,
             style: {
                 "fontSize": "10px"
             }
         },
         tickInterval: 1800000,
         gridLineWidth: 1
     },
     series: [{
         data: [{
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483336800000,
                 high: 1483336860000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483336860000,
                 high: 1483337340000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483337340000,
                 high: 1483337400000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483337400000,
                 high: 1483337700000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483337700000,
                 high: 1483339920000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483341780000,
                 high: 1483342260000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483345080000,
                 high: 1483345140000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483346400000,
                 high: 1483346460000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483347420000,
                 high: 1483347600000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483347600000,
                 high: 1483347780000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483347780000,
                 high: 1483348020000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483348200000,
                 high: 1483352460000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483352640000,
                 high: 1483352700000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483353840000,
                 high: 1483354920000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483355160000,
                 high: 1483359480000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483361460000,
                 high: 1483361520000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483361520000,
                 high: 1483361580000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483361760000,
                 high: 1483361820000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483361820000,
                 high: 1483362060000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
             {
                 x: 1,
                 low: 1483362060000,
                 high: 1483364280000,
                 color: '#3366cc'
             },
         ]
     }]
 }
 );
```

I have tired to set it as the following but without seccuss:

```
{globaloptions: {global:  {useUTC: false}}}
```

Comment: This problem cannot be reproduced with the information you gave. You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jp8amr4g/) that setOptions works correctly. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to create a live example of the problem.

Comment: @morganfree Please take a look at the new code.

Comment: setOptions() works in jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0zw7gq82/1/

Comment: @morganfree: yes it works in the jsfiddle but I can not use setOption() when building the String in the java class. Therefoe I am looking for another way to set it in the `globaloption` configuration

Comment: As far as I know this is the only available API for changing UTC options. You can include setting options in the global file and load it as a script in your webpage - setOptions affects all charts anyway